# Internet Connection Sharing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ics

Actually i have seen that while enabling ICS in earlier version the LAN NIC will take IP address as 192.168.0.1, but in win 7 i observed that it takes 192.168.137.1. can anyone tel me why?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge ICS can be set to have IP address obtained automatically or statically by setting the subnet to 255.255.255.0.

So in your situation, can you explain how you have your configuration ?